# How do I get the file path of the selected file using open file dialog without double clicking the file or clicking "open"?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I've been looking around and can't quite find what I'm looking for.  I understand how to use openfiledialog in the traditional way but is it possible to get the file path by single clicking on a file and not closing the dialog box? I want the user to be able to click on a file in the openfiledialog box and view the file in a picturebox without the dialog box closing.  Only until they select "open" do I want the dialog box to close.

Comment: I think you need to build a custom file dialog for that.

Comment: Suggested reading: [What is a Modal Dialog Window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045)

Comment: The standard openfiledialog already has a preview pane, if someone wants to use it. What filetype do you want to open with the dialog? Is there no previewhandler registered for your filetype?

Comment: @Steeeve the file type is .ipt.  It's an Autodesk Inventor file (3d model), which does show up in the preview pane as a picture as you mentioned but I would like for the user to be able to rotate, zoom in, etc. on the part.  I'm using Inventor's api that loads the part into a picturebox and the user can interact with the part.  After doing some more reading, it looks like it may not be possible to get, and use, the file's path from a modal dialog box while it is still open.

Comment: There are some hooks for the dialog, I don't know if they still work. But have a look at [Extend OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog the Easy Way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-Easy)